# Angular : How to inject concret class in the parent component

Tags: angular

I have a common component

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'mc-common',
  ...
})
CommonComponent {

 constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() private readonly mergingStrategy: MergingStrategy) {
    if (!this.mergingStrategy) {
      this.mergingStrategy = new NoopMergingStrategy();
    }
 }
 ...
}
```

And another component which uses the `mc-common`

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'mc-another',
  template: `
     <mc-commo>
      ...
     </mc-common>
  `,
  providers: [{
    provide: MergingStrategy, useClass: ComplicatedMergingStrategy // or useValue: new ComplicatedMergingStrategy()
  }
})
AnotherComponent {

 constructor(private readonly mergingStrategy: MergingStrategy) {

 }
 ...
}
```

So when I'm calling `mc-another`, `mc-common` will take `ComplicatedMergingStrategy` as instance of `MergingStrategy`.

Everything is working fine like this. But what I want to achieve is injecting the **same instance** of `ComplicatedMerginStrategy` into `AnotherComponent` rather than the abstraction but continuing to use the abstraction in the `mc-common`.

Something like:

```js
AnotherComponent {

 constructor(private readonly mergingStrategy: ComplicatedMergingStrategy) {

 }
 ...
}
```

The strategies :

```js
abstract class MergingStrategy {
  merge(a, b): any
}

class NoopMergingStrategy implements MergingStrategy {
   merge(a, b): any {
    return a;
   }
}

class ComplicatedMergingStrategy implements MergingStrategy {
   merge(a, b) {
    ...
   }
}
```

I hope I'm clear :)

Comment: I guess you've tried injecting MerginStrategy and/or ComplicatedMerginStrategy using @Injectable() above the 'export class ...' definition right ?

Comment: `@Injectable()` won't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is `useExisting` and declare the instance of `ComplicatedMerginStrategy` before.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'mc-another',
  template: `
     <mc-commo>
      ...
     </mc-common>
  `,
  providers: [
    ComplicatedMerginStrategy, {
    provide: MerginStrategy, useExisting: ComplicatedMerginStrategy
  }]
})
AnotherComponent {

 constructor(private readonly merginStrategy: ComplicatedMerginStrategy) {

 }
 ...
}
```